# FabricJS Problem with clipPath on a video

Tags: fabricjs, clip-path

The video is not played correctly when a clipPath is attached to the object.

The video updates the frames only when you resize the object.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var videoEl = document.getElementById('video');

var clipText = new fabric.Text('My Custom Text', { 
    left: 'center',
    top: 'center', 
    fontSize: 40,
});

var video = new fabric.Image(videoEl, {
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    angle: 0,
    originX: 0,
    originY: 0,
    objectCaching: false,
    clipPath: clipText,
    backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
});

canvas.add(video);
video.getElement().play();

fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
  canvas.renderAll();
  fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like fabric.js relies heavily on caching when Image object has a clipPath.

During the render call, it checks `this.needsItsOwnCache()` which returns `true` because `this.clipPath` is present.
Then it calls `this.renderCache()`, which only updates the cached canvas if `this.isCacheDirty()` returns `true`.

For it to return true, you can utilize the object's [`statefullCache`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#statefullCache) and [`cacheProperties`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#cacheProperties) setting a custom `videoTime` property with a value of video element's `currentTime`.
Then you just make sure to update `videoTime` on each animation frame.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
const clipText = new fabric.Text("My Custom Text", {
  left: "center",
  top: "center",
  fontSize: 36
});
const videoEl = document.querySelector("#video");
const video = new fabric.Image(videoEl, {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  angle: 0,
  originX: 0,
  originY: 0,
  objectCaching: true,
  statefullCache: true,
  cacheProperties: ['videoTime'],
  clipPath: clipText,
  backgroundColor: "#ff0000"
});
canvas.add(video);
video.getElement().play();
fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
  canvas.renderAll();
  video.videoTime = videoEl.currentTime;
  fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
});
document.querySelector("#button").onclick = () => {
  video.clipPath = video.clipPath == null ? clipText : null;
};
```

```css
body {
  background: ivory;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
  <video id="video" width="240" height="180" autoplay loop muted >
    <source src="https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<button id="button">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear answer. It works perfectly!